# Media option not works while printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cant get the tr background color while print.

My code is below. Please specify what wrong with the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Employee</title>
<style type="text/css">
@media all {
tr.header {
    background-color: red;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body >
<table border="1" bordercolor="#B4B4B4" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Sex</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>MartialStatus</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Emailid</th>
      <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Radha Krishnan </td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>Un Married</td>
      <td>Coimbatore</td>
      <td>test@asasa.com</td>
      <td>Team Lead</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ramesh Kumar</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Un Married</td>
      <td>Trivandrum</td>
      <td>rameshk@asdasd.com</td>
      <td>Senior Programmer/Analyst</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mohan Ram</td>
      <td>Male</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>Married</td>
      <td>sfgsd</td>
      <td>asfasf@asfasf.com</td>
      <td>Programmer/Analyst</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: For CSS tr.header I had given display: none; it seems work. I cant predict why background-color is not accepted.

Comment: Are you sure that other element's backgrounds are printed correct. Many users turn off background printing in their browsers. Many browsers has this setting turned on (don't print any background) by defaults. Are you sure, that your problem is in CSS not in browser?

Comment: Agree with trejder, many browsers do not print background colors by default; it is often an option that has to be enabled by the user.

Comment: Where we need to enable in fire fox